# PayPal express ActiveMerchant gateway not working

Tags: ruby, jruby, activemerchant, paypal

According to [this](http://jldbasa.github.io/blog/2014/01/25/rails-4-paypal-express-checkout-integration/), the ActiveMerchant PayPal Express Gateway is initialized like this:

```
paypal_options = {
  login: "API_USERNAME_HERE",
  password: "API_PASSWORD_HERE",
  signature: "API_SIGNATURE_HERE"
}

::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
```

I'm definitely supplying a signature, yet I'm getting this error:

> An API Certificate or API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal

The PayPal initializer looks like this (found [here](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_common_api.rb)):

```
def initialize(options = {})
    requires!(options, :login, :password)

    headers = {'X-PP-AUTHORIZATION' => options.delete(:auth_signature), 'X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL' => 'SOAP11'} if options[:auth_signature]
    options = {
        :pem => pem_file,
        :signature => signature,
        :headers => headers || {}
    }.update(options)

    if options[:pem].blank? && options[:signature].blank?
        raise ArgumentError, "An API Certificate or API Signature is required to make requests to PayPal"
    end

    super(options)
end
```

I don't understand what this initializer is doing with the signature and why it's not accepting it as per the example.

Here are the options I'm passing, which I've put to STDOUT:

```
{  
   "password"   =>"***************",
   "signature"   =>"AVtrAKGQXoUNJFduUU0pn1dewq80AK9KYWenyFwYcduz8elS85B8T0Wc",
   "allow_guest_checkout"   =>true,
   "login"   =>"********************",
   "test"   =>true
}
```

Can someone help me with this please?
Note that I'm using this in JRuby, but I don't think that makes any difference in this case.

---

**EDIT after @PiersC's comments:**

I hardcoded this instead of taking them as params from Java and it worked:

```
  options = {
      login: "*************",
      password: "*****************",
      signature: "AVtrAKGQXoUNJFduUU0pn1dewq80AK9KYWenyFwYcduz8elS85B8T0Wc"
  }
```

However this has led to another question. I've been converting the Java maps to Ruby hashes like this:

```
def self.convert_hash(map)
    hsh = {}
    map.each {|key, value| hsh[key] = value}
    hsh.with_indifferent_access
end
```

And this has worked on all other gateways. How do I convert the Java map **correctly** to the options hash in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option keys are strings but should be symbols, eg. { password: '***', ... }  ActiveSupport::HashWithInvalidAccess hides (obscures?) the difference between symbol keys and string keys, but if you are using a regular Hash then { 'signature' => signature } is not the same as { signature: signature }.

Comment: I think that's just the way `puts` is printing them. None of the other gateways are complaining and the code is common. My assumption is that this is doing something nasty: `:signature => signature`. What is the `signature` doing in this context?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. It's worth fiddling with inspect and `puts h['signature']` vs. `puts h[:signature]`

Comment: I updated the question because the comment wouldn't allow the response.

Comment: This is resolved. The key was to convert the java map like this: `def self.convert_hash(map)
    hsh = {}
    map.each {|key, value| hsh[key] = value}
    hsh.symbolize_keys
  end
`